# Error installing GMP

Tags: c++, gmp

I'm on OSX Lion using TextMate to write my C++ programs. I wanted to deal with some large numbers and thus tried installing GMP. Here's what I did.

1. I installed gmp 5.0.4 from gmplib.org
2. After downloading, I navigated to the directory in terminal and executed ./configure. Output: http://pastebin.com/2M4AEgR6
3. Execute make. Output: http://pastebin.com/8TrjST2D

I tried consulting the [Installing GMP manual](http://gmplib.org/manual/Installing-GMP.html) and that's what it says to do. g++ is running fine on my computer. What might be going wrong?

Comment: Oh wait. I figured it out. All I had to do was to open the file causing the 'Operation not permitted' error and subsequently click 'allow' in the dialog that opens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comments:

> Oh wait. I figured it out. All I had to do was to open the file causing the `Operation not permitted` error and subsequently click `allow` in the dialog that opens.